# iNEXT with 0 values

Tags: r, inext

I am applying iNEXT to the following data but I get an error. To my observation, my data is organized the same as the spider data as used by the authors for examples.

```
dput(corn.list)
 list(A = structure(c("C2_blk1_2014", "   0", "300", "1350", " 150", 
"  0", "   0", "300", "1350", " 150", "  0", "   0", "300", "1350", 
"C2_blk1_2015", "   0", "  0", "1264", " 702", "  0", "   0", 
"  0", "1264", " 702", "  0", "   0", "  0", "1264", "C2_blk1_2016", 
"   0", "  0", "1674", " 913", "  0", "   0", "  0", "1674", 
" 913", "  0", "   0", "  0", "1674", "C2_blk1_2017", "1112", 
"  0", "5423", " 973", "  0", "1112", "  0", "5423", " 973", 
"  0", "1112", "  0", "5423", "C2_blk2_2014", " 142", "  0", 
" 994", " 568", "  0", " 142", "  0", " 994", " 568", "  0", 
" 142", "  0", " 994", "C2_blk2_2015", "   0", "  0", " 305", 
" 611", "  0", "   0", "  0", " 305", " 611", "  0", "   0", 
"  0", " 305", "C2_blk2_2016", "   0", "  0", "2266", "1133", 
"  0", "   0", "  0", "2266", "1133", "  0", "   0", "  0", "2266", 
"C2_blk2_2017", " 131", "  0", "1705", "1049", "  0", " 131", 
"  0", "1705", "1049", "  0", " 131", "  0", "1705", "C2_blk3_2014", 
"   0", "  0", " 834", "   0", "  0", "   0", "  0", " 834", 
"   0", "  0", "   0", "  0", " 834", "C2_blk3_2015", "   0", 
"  0", " 834", " 556", "  0", "   0", "  0", " 834", " 556", 
"  0", "   0", "  0", " 834", "C2_blk3_2016", " 272", "  0", 
"2446", "1223", "  0", " 272", "  0", "2446", "1223", "  0", 
" 272", "  0", "2446", "C2_blk3_2017", "   0", "  0", "3466", 
"1600", "  0", "   0", "  0", "3466", "1600", "  0", "   0", 
"  0", "3466", "C2_blk4_2014", " 136", "  0", "   0", " 272", 
"136", " 136", "  0", "   0", " 272", "136", " 136", "  0", "   0", 
"C2_blk4_2015", "   0", "  0", " 725", " 290", "  0", "   0", 
"  0", " 725", " 290", "  0", "   0", "  0", " 725", "C2_blk4_2016", 
" 136", "136", "2996", "3405", "  0", " 136", "136", "2996", 
"3405", "  0", " 136", "136", "2996", "C2_blk4_2017", "   0", 
"  0", " 958", " 274", "  0", "   0", "  0", " 958", " 274", 
"  0", "   0", "  0", " 958"), .Dim = c(14L, 16L), .Dimnames = list(
c("id", "SETSP", "SOLPT", "SONAR", "AMATA", "MORAL", "POLCO", 
"CHEAL", "DIGSA", "DATST", "ABUTH", "POLPY", "POLPE", "SONAS"
), NULL)), B = structure(c("C4_blk1_2014", "   0", "  0", 
"  966", " 966", "  0", "  0", "  0", "   0", "  0", "  966", 
" 966", "  0", "  0", "C4_blk1_2015", " 935", "  0", " 1247", 
" 779", "  0", "312", "  0", " 935", "  0", " 1247", " 779", 
"  0", "312", "C4_blk1_2016", " 134", "  0", "  668", " 936", 
"  0", "  0", "  0", " 134", "  0", "  668", " 936", "  0", "  0", 
"C4_blk1_2017", "   0", "136", "  819", "1092", "  0", "  0", 
"  0", "   0", "136", "  819", "1092", "  0", "  0", "C4_blk2_2014", 
 " 138", "  0", "  276", " 414", "  0", "  0", "  0", " 138", 
"  0", "  276", " 414", "  0", "  0", "C4_blk2_2015", "   0", 
"  0", "  755", "1962", "302", "  0", "  0", "   0", "  0", "  755", 
"1962", "302", "  0", "C4_blk2_2016", " 144", "432", " 1728", 
" 288", "  0", "  0", "  0", " 144", "432", " 1728", " 288", 
"  0", "  0", "C4_blk2_2017", "   0", "138", "10091", "2626", 
"  0", "  0", "  0", "   0", "138", "10091", "2626", "  0", "  0", 
"C4_blk3_2014", "   0", "272", " 2040", " 136", "  0", "  0", 
"  0", "   0", "272", " 2040", " 136", "  0", "  0", "C4_blk3_2015", 
"1444", "  0", "  289", "   0", "  0", "  0", "  0", "1444", 

"  0", "  289", "   0", "  0", "  0", "C4_blk3_2016", " 407", 
"  0", "    0", " 136", "  0", "  0", "  0", " 407", "  0", "    0", 
" 136", "  0", "  0", "C4_blk3_2017", " 135", "  0", "  812", 
" 812", "  0", "  0", "  0", " 135", "  0", "  812", " 812", 
"  0", "  0", "C4_blk4_2014", "   0", "  0", "  548", " 548", 
"  0", "  0", "  0", "   0", "  0", "  548", " 548", "  0", "  0", 
"C4_blk4_2015", " 723", "  0", "  434", "1592", "  0", "  0", 
"  0", " 723", "  0", "  434", "1592", "  0", "  0", "C4_blk4_2016", 
"   0", "  0", " 1599", " 666", "  0", "  0", "  0", "   0", 
"  0", " 1599", " 666", "  0", "  0", "C4_blk4_2017", " 135", 
"135", " 3781", "1621", "  0", "  0", "135", " 135", "135", " 3781", 
"1621", "  0", "  0"), .Dim = c(14L, 16L), .Dimnames = list(c("id", 
"SETSP", "SOLPT", "SONAR", "AMATA", "MORAL", "POLCO", "CHEAL", 
"DIGSA", "DATST", "ABUTH", "POLPY", "POLPE", "SONAS"), NULL)))
```

Code
`iNEXT(corn.list,q=0,datatype = "abundance")`

Error

```
Error in if (sum(x) == 0) stop("Zero abundance counts in one or more sample sites") : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Spider data here
http://johnsonhsieh.github.io/iNEXT/inst/doc/Introduction.html

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your list is likely to be interpreted by R as being composed of character, rather than numeric vectors. iNEXT needs your data to be of type "numeric," which means that R understands the values inside to be numbers rather than strings of characters. See how R understands the spider data to be two named vectors each with only numeric values, using the `str()` function:

```
 > str(spider)
 List of 2
 $ Girdled: num [1:26] 46 22 17 15 15 9 8 6 6 4 ...
 $ Logged : num [1:37] 88 22 16 15 13 10 8 8 7 7 ...
```

Your data are understood to be lists of character strings, instead

```
> str(corn.list)
List of 2

$ A: chr [1:14, 1:16] "C2_blk1_2014" "   0" "300" "1350" ...
..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. ..$ : chr [1:14] "id" "SETSP" "SOLPT" "SONAR" ...
.. ..$ : NULL
$ B: chr [1:14, 1:16] "C4_blk1_2014" "   0" "  0" "  966" ...
..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. ..$ : chr [1:14] "id" "SETSP" "SOLPT" "SONAR" ...
.. ..$ : NULL
```

To save you time, it will probably be easier to start with your original data file and upload it so that R understands the structure better (I usually use `read.csv()`).

It would be possible to reformat it in R. I started down this road, but realized quickly that my rough code will remove your strain names and mess up the alignment of each of your "communities," which you'll need for iNEXT. Anyways, I've pasted my code below in case it is of some use to you as a staring point or reference.

```
#first create a function that will convert your data to numeric   
replace_space<-function(strng){as.numeric(gsub(" ", "", strng))}

#then apply the function to every column in each element of your list
cl2<-lapply(corn.list, function(x){sapply(x, replace_space)})

#Things that were legitimate character strings get converted to NA. if you didn't care about them at all, you could remove them: 
cl3<-lapply(cl2, function(x){apply(x,2, function(y){y[complete.cases(y)]})})
```